# Why matplotlib can show the image instead of cv2.imshow?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, opencv, python

I can show the sample image with the matplotlib's `pyplot.plt.show`.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt    
img = cv2.imread('sample.jpeg',1)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.show()
```

Now turn to cvs's image show.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2    
img = cv2.imread('sample.jpeg',1)
cv2.imshow('image',img)
```

I wonder why `cv2.imshow` can't show the image. How to check what's the matter for my `cv2`?

[image]

Comment: Also when drawing with cv2, `plt.show()` needs to be called at the end. Internally, cv2 is using matplotlib for drawing.

Comment: After `cv2.imshow` you must execute `cv2.waitKey`.